# Can I play GTA Online if my disc is unreadable?

Tags: xbox-360, grand-theft-auto-online

I own a physical copy of *GTA V* but it is too scratched to install on my son's Xbox 360. How do I prove ownership so he can just play *GTA Online*?

Comment: I will not buy this video game, it is scratched.

Comment: You may want to contact Rockstar. There are some instances of people calling the developers and proving ownership to receive a digital certificate (Persona Q being a famous case)

Answer (score 1):

***GTA Online* can't be played on Xbox 360 and PlayStation 3** (as of December 16, 2021). Only *GTA V* Story Mode can be played on Xbox 360 and PlayStation 3. Contact [Rockstar Games Support](https://support.rockstargames.com/) to prove ownership and have *GTA V* activated on your Xbox 360.

According to the Rockstar Games announcement post, [GTA Online for PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 Will Shut Down on December 16, 2021](https://www.rockstargames.com/newswire/article/51989315o2aa3a/gta-online-for-playstation-3-and-xbox-360-will-shut-down-on-december-1):

> ...the PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 versions of GTA Online, including website stat tracking via the Rockstar Games Social Club, will officially be shutting down on December 16, 2021.

> Please note, these changes are strictly for the PS3 and Xbox 360 versions of GTA Online, and will have no impact on access to, or progress within, the Grand Theft Auto V Story Mode.

From the Rockstar Games Support article, [End of online services for PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 versions of GTAV, Max Payne 3 and L.A. Noire FAQ](https://support.rockstargames.com/articles/1500012375661/End-of-online-services-for-PlayStation-3-and-Xbox-360-versions-of-GTAV-Max-Payne-3-and-L-A-Noire-FAQ):

> GTA Online on PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360
>
> - September 16, 2021
>
>   - PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 versions of Shark Cards for GTA Online no longer sold.
> - December 16, 2021
>
>   - GTA Online services for PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 versions, including website stat tracking via the Rockstar Games Social Club no
>     longer available.
>   - GTA V Story Mode for PlayStation 3 and Xbox 360 not impacted.

Comment: I knew they were ending online support but I didn't know it was so soon! Besides I don't have a receipt anymore, it's not like I bought it recently, so how exactly would I prove ownership short of just taking a picture of the disc and my face with my license also in the picture and my Rockstar account ID written down somewhere in the picture as well? For example..